# Best way to constrain a complex number to being within the unit circle?

Tags: floating-point, numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis

What is the best way of implementing the following function,

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\max(1, |x|)},$$

where $x$ is complex, using a Cartesian representation of $x$ with IEEE 754 floating point representations (i.e., `float` or `double`) for the real and imaginary parts such that $|f(x)| \leq 1$ for all possible values of $x$?

Yves Daoust points out that the problem becomes trivial if $x$ is represented with polar coordinates. While true, a Cartesian representation is much more convenient and computationally efficient for various operations, such as taking the difference between complex numbers, and so while this problem might be motivation to move to a polar representation, I'm eager to know if there are standard approaches already known in the case of a Cartesian representation.

The language doesn't matter, but let's say for argument's sake that we're using C++:

```
std::complex<double> f_impl(std::complex<double> x);
```

Is the immediate implementation of

```
std::complex<double> f_impl(std::complex<double> x)
{
  return x/std::max(1., std::abs(x));
}
```

guaranteed to work, i.e., so that `std::norm(f_impl(x)) <= 1` for every possible `x`? I haven't been able to prove that rounding errors will not occasionally allow degenerative values to fail this property. We can perhaps temporarily change the floating point rounding mode to help us, but this doesn't feel ideal. I'm posting the current question as I feel there's more to this than meets the eye and I'm keen to discover whether there are known techniques or literature regarding this problem.

To illustrate the potential depth of the problem, consider the following properties that we may care about. I don't know of proper terminology for them, so I'll define some terms and be grateful for better suggestions:

*Strict in magnitude*: `f_impl` is *strict in magnitude* iff `std::norm(f_impl(x)) == 1` for all possible values of `x` such that `std::norm(x) >= 1`.

*Monotonic in magnitude*: `f_impl` is *monotonic in magnitude* iff `std::norm(f_impl(x)) >= std::norm(f_impl(y))` for all possible values of `x` and `y` such that `std::norm(x) >= std::norm(y)`.

*Weakly monotonic in magnitude*: `f_impl` is *weakly monotonic in magnitude* iff `std::norm(f_impl(c*x)) >= std::norm(x)` for all possible values of `x` and `c >= 1`, `c` being real.

*Strict in argument*: `f_impl` is *strict in argument* iff `std::arg(f_impl(x)) == std::arg(x)` for all possible values of `x`.

*Strictly scaling*: `f_impl` is *strictly scaling* iff for every possible `x` there exists some `c` such that `f_impl(x) == c*x`.

Ideally we would want all 5 properties to be satisfied, but due to finite precision, we may be forced to sacrifice one or more properties. If we sacrifice the strict in argument property, then we should define another property, *biased in argument*, which reflects whether the function has a tendency to rotate in one direction more than the other, e.g., by quantifying the expected rotation. It seems reasonable to me that the most important properties for most applications will be weakly monotonic in magnitude and strictly scaling.

Beyond considering which properties are met, it's of course interesting to consider how computationally efficient the implementation can be made. In my case, it should be very unusual to see values for which `std::norm(x) > 1`, and so a trivial branching approach is acceptable and fast. However, it's easy to imagine applications (e.g., in DSP) where most points are expected to lie outside the unit circle and where efficiency is crucial.

To provide some context and a motivating example, this problem cropped up when working with the wrapped Cauchy distribution, which is parametrised by $\zeta$, a complex number that must lie within the unit circle. If it is outwith the unit circle, then otherwise-reasonable implementations of its pdf produce negative values. While the pdf can be implemented to be tolerant of $\zeta$ values lying just outwith the unit circle, by far the cleanest approach is to ensure that `std::norm(zeta) <= 1` in the first place, hence my interest in this problem.

Edit: I've realised, prompted by YvesDaoust, that `std::norm(x) <= 1` isn't an ideal predicate of whether `x` lies within the unit circle, because the return type of `std::norm()` isn't sufficiently wide to be representative of whether `x` is within the unit circle. I've not edit the question as I'd end up making substantial changes and I feel the intent is still clear, even with this slight inaccuracy. Ideally, the reader would interpret `std::norm(x)` as returning a floating point representation wide enough to encode the squared magnitude of `x` without loss of precision.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Good point, have edited the question to be explicit that it's regarding a Cartesian representation. But you raise a valid point, given that the problem feels at least analytically difficult, it would certainly be more pragmatic to move over to a polar representation; most applications would tolerate the difference in computational efficiency. But this feels like a problem that must have already been investigated at some point, so I'm really keen to know what prior conclusions have been reached.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Achieving `std::norm(x) <= 1` is almost by definition keeping `x` inside the unit circle, but I confess, there is potential for loss of the precision in the addition and so it would be possible for `std::norm(x) == 1` to be true while simultaneously `(((long double) x.real())*x.real() + ((long double) x.imag())*x.imag())) > 1` also being true. I think you're right: I should have defined the 5 properties to take this into account.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, that's true, but keeping $x$ in the unit circle is a very natural and common thing in many fields of maths/engineering, so from that perspective, the answer is resoundly "yes, $|x| \leq 1$ is a clean/meaningful predicate". Also worth mentioning that $x$ lying exactly upon the unit circle (rather than within it) is in no way regressive or degenerative; that's an entirely valid parametrisation and one that can occur quite naturally (again, not just limited to my particular application).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think you misunderstand. I am not asking about keeping $x$ on the unit circle, which I agree would be problematic. I am asking regarding preventing it from being outwith the unit circle. It does not have to have unit magnitude. This is absolutely a valid thing to want to do (see, e.g., many applications in DSP).